# Ordenar palavras com acentos em PHP

Tags: php, array, classificação

Estou tentando ordenar alfabeticamente um array em PHP, onde a chave de cada posição do array é uma palavra.

Estou usando a função [`ksort`](https://www.php.net/ksort). A ordenação funciona, o problema é que palavras acentuadas como por exemplo "ácido" são colocadas no fim da lista.

Preciso fazer com que as letras acentuadas sejam ordenadas da mesmas forma que letras não acentuadas e que o procedimento não demande muito processamento.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Teste assim, usando:

```
$palavras = array('ambiente', 'anão', 'anã', 'pai', 'país', 'ácido');
function compareASCII($a, $b) {
    $at = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $a);
    $bt = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $b);
    return strcmp($at, $bt);
}

uasort($palavras, 'compareASCII');
var_dump($palavras);
```

O resultado é:

```
array(6) {
  [5]=>
  string(6) "ácido"
  [0]=>
  string(8) "ambiente"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "anã"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "anão"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "pai"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "país"
}
```

<sub>Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10649560/2256325</sub>

Essa função `uasort(<array>, <função>)` aceita como segundo parametro uma outra função para comparar os valores da array.

Comment: Estava olhando a mesma resposta do stack overflow. Acho interessante explicar como as funções `u*sort` funcionam no php (através de callback e etc).

Comment: Essa função funciona para ordenar os valores do array. Mas no caso eu preciso ordenar as chaves do mesmo.

Comment: @TércioGarcia subtitua o `a` por `k`. Acho que cabe uma explicação ainda mais detalhada do comportamento das funções sort.

Comment: Entendi agora, funcionou com o uksort. Obrigado!

Comment: @gmsantos vou juntar mais daqwui a pouco, obrigaod

Comment: Por que então, por exemplo, o nome Marília vem antes de Marcela? Façam o teste com um array com estes dois nomes e vejam.

Answer (score 1):

A [solução que o Sérgio indicou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/35425/67260) não funcionou pra mim, já que, por algum motivo, ela colocou as palavras que começam com acento antes do resto das palavras:

```
array(4) {
    ["Ética_Profissional"]=>
    array(2) {
        [0]=>
        int(12864)
        [1]=>
        int(12862)
    }
    ["Computação_Aplicada"]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        int(12861)
    }
    ["Geologia_Ambiental_e_Recursos_Hídricos"]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        int(11803)
        }
    ["Socioeconomia_e_Sustentabilidade"]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        int(12858)
    }
}
```

Porém, eu encontrei [neste post](https://web.archive.org/web/20171224235927/http://www.andrescampanario.es/es/blog/ordenar_array_alfabeticamente_teniendo_en_cuenta_acentos_en_php) uma solução que funcionou pra mim:

```
$key_values = array(
    'Geologia_Ambiental_e_Recursos_Hídricos'    => array( 11803 ),
    'Computação_Aplicada'                       => array( 12861 ),
    'Socioeconomia_e_Sustentabilidade'          => array( 12858 ),
    'Ética_Profissional'                        => array( 12864, 12862 ),
);
function comparar_palavras($name1,$name2){
    $patterns = array(
        'a' => '(á|à|â|ä|ã|Á|À|Â|Ä|Ã)',
        'e' => '(é|è|ê|ë|É|È|Ê|Ë)',
        'i' => '(í|ì|î|ï|Í|Ì|Î|Ï)',
        'o' => '(ó|ò|ô|ö|õ|Ó|Ò|Ô|Ö|Õ)',
        'u' => '(ú|ù|û|ü|Ú|Ù|Û|Ü)'
    );          
    $name1 = preg_replace(array_values($patterns), array_keys($patterns), $name1);
    $name2 = preg_replace(array_values($patterns), array_keys($patterns), $name2);          
    return strcasecmp($name1, $name2);
}
uksort($key_values, "comparar_palavras");
```

O resultado fica:

```
array(4) {
    ["Computação_Aplicada"]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        int(12861)
    }
    ["Ética_Profissional"]=>
    array(2) {
        [0]=>
        int(12864)
        [1]=>
        int(12862)
    }
    ["Geologia_Ambiental_e_Recursos_Hídricos"]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        int(11803)
    }
    ["Socioeconomia_e_Sustentabilidade"]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        int(12858)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Minha abordagem utiliza a função nativa do PHP, [array_multisort](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-multisort.php). Você não precisa mexer no array original e pode utilizar uma grande gama de recursos dessa função. Você pode, ainda, utlizar arrays multi-dimensionais, utilizando array_column, para ordenar a coluna que você quer, e depois fazer referência com o array original.

(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7, PHP 8)

array_multisort — Ordena múltiplos arrays ou arrays multidimensionais

```
  // Função para substituir caracteres especiais
  function accentReplace($string){
    $wAccent  = ['à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ù', 'ü', 'ú', 'ÿ', 'À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ù', 'Ü', 'Ú'];
    $woAccent = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'U'];
    return str_replace($wAccent, $woAccent, $string);
  }

  // Array de dados
  $data = ['João','Maria','José','Jose','Joao','MARIA'];

  // Definindo índice
  $index = array_map(
  function ($el) {
    return mb_strtoupper(accentReplace($el));
  },
  $data);

 // Ordena array $data baseado nas chaves em comum com array $index
 array_multisort($index, SORT_ASC, $data);

 // Resultado
 print_r($data);
```

Answer (score -3):

Consegui da seguinte maneira:

```
$campos = [
    15 => 'analista',
    21 => 'Usuário',
    8  => 'Área de Atuação'
];

uasort($campos, function ($a, $b) {
    return collator_compare(new Collator('pt_BR'), $a, $b);
});

foreach ($campos as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value\n";
}
```

Comment: Você chegou a testar esse código? Pois é eu testei e não funcionou. Na verdade o problema da pergunta se mantém inalterado. https://onlinephp.io/c/22496

Comment: eu usei aqui, mas teve umas alterações...
o que aqui funcionou foi usar o uasort com collator_compare(new Collator('pt_BR'), $a, $b);, isso foi possível para fazer a ordenação correta no exemplo de array