# Por que um método de sort não funciona corretamente em servidores LINUX?

Tags: php, linux, classificação

Tenho uma dúvida, eu tenho uma função para ordenar um `array` que possuí nomes de pessoas com acentuação (UTF-8). Funciona corretamente em servidores WINDOWS, mas quando lanço o código para rodar em servidores LINUX a acentuação fica com interrogação e não ordena corretamente o que será ? Já consultei todos os tutoriais de "[Ordenar palavras com acentos em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35424/ordenar-palavras-com-acentos-em-php])", e todos usam o método conforme utilizo. Já tentei `usort` `uksort` `uasort` nenhum funcionou.

```
arrayMembros[$arrayDados2[0]] = array("idUsuario" => @$arrayDados2[0] , "nome" => ucwords(strtolower(utf8_encode(@$arrayDados2[1]))) , "sobrenome" => ucwords(strtolower(utf8_encode(@$arrayDados2[2])))    );

uasort(

    $arrayMembros,

     function( $a, $b ) {
        $variavela = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $a["nome"]);
        $variavelb = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $b["nome"]);

         return strcmp($variavela, $variavelb);
     }
);
```

Resultado no servidor LINUX:

- ?nio Lima
- Alana Siqueira
- Fulana da Silva

Resultado esperado (e também resultado no servidor WINDOWS):

- Alana Siqueira
- Ênio Lima
- Fulana da Silva

Não me peçam para remover o `utf8_encode` do código, pois já o fiz e dá no mesmo, só que ao invés da interrogação pura, o resultado é a interrogação em losango. 
Os dados veem de arquivos de texto e quero exibi-los diretamente na página sem que tenha que inseri-los em um banco de dados e dá um comando `ORDER` para que os dados venham ordenados.

Código:

```
$url = file_get_contents(verificar()."GERAL_getUsuariosGrupo.asp?idGrupo='$idGrupo'");

    $arrayDados = explode(";;",$url);
    $arrayMembros = array();
    $arrayMembros2 = array();

    foreach($arrayDados as $dados){
        $arrayDados2 = explode("|",$dados);
        $arrayMembros[$arrayDados2[0]] = array("idUsuario" => @$arrayDados2[0] , "nome" => ucwords(strtolower(@$arrayDados2[1])) , "sobrenome" => ucwords(strtolower(@$arrayDados2[2]))    );
        }


        usort(

    $arrayMembros,

     function( $a, $b ) {
        $variavela = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $a["nome"]);
        $variavelb = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $b["nome"]);

         return strcmp($variavela, $variavelb);
     }
);
```

Ps.: desde já agradeço e peço desculpas por não conseguir comentar no link que sugeri a cima, pois essa política do stackoverflow de 50 pontos de reputação para poder comentar me forçou a abrir outra discussão.

Comment: Tente usar `usort`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters já tentei "usort" "uksort" "uasort" e nenhum deu certo.

Comment: isso é um típico problema de má configuração do charset encode.. vc pode resolver implementando diversas gambiarras, mas aconselho a configurar e consertar charset do ambiente.

Comment: @DanielOmine tudo bem ? Olha, fiz o que você indicou realmente no servidor linux estava sem a variável `default_charset`, estava NULL. Corrigi e coloquei  `default_charset=UTF-8`, consultei usando a função `phpinfo()` e agora está como padrão UTF-8. Porém, mesmo assim a ordenação não ocorre corretamente, embora tenha corrigido o problema com o **Bootstrap** ao invés da interrogação, agora está aparecendo normalmente o nome "Ênio Lima" só que na parte superior a cima de Alana Siqueira.

Comment: Maicon, isso só não resolve. É um assunto muito amplo para poder te explicar nesse curto espaço dos comentários.. Na verdade não precisa modificar configurações no servidor, pois no php é possível setar em tempo de execução.. Mas enfim, depende de outros fatores, como por exemplo, se os dados estão íntegros, ou seja sem nenhum tipo de corrompimento. Por isso é complicado dar uma resposta exata. Exige-se um diagnóstico mais minucioso. Apenas te aconselho a não sair por aí executando tudo que te indicarm porque aí corre risco de corromper dados, piorando a situação.. para segurança , faça backup

Comment: Valeu @DanielOmine. Estou sim mantendo os backups mas minha grande preocupação é em resolver essa situação, em `C`, `Java` não encontrava muitas situações como essas por se tratarem de linguagens desktop, e nunca necessitei propriamente dito fazer uma ordenação de string com `array` em `PHP`, tendo em vista que usava os comandos `ORDER` do banco de dados, mas nessa situação recebo dados de arquivos de texto  e seria ridículo ter que inserir esses dados no banco, ler ordenadamente e exibir da forma que quero, mas enquanto não encontro uma solução acho que vai ser a saída.

Comment: isso muda muito o contexto da sua questão.. sugiro que adicione esse seu ultimo comentário na propria pergunta pois fica bem mais claro o objetivo e até mais fácil de encontrar solução.. aliás, sei como resolver..

Comment: @DanielOmine qual seria a sugestão de testes para que possamos chegar em uma resposta?

Comment: há muitos tipos de testes, mas eu começaria verificando o tipo de encode dos dados.. no php há uma função chamada mb_detect_encode(). Leia no manual para saber como usar. http://php.net/mb_detect_encode

Comment: Por favor poste o script inteiro de maneira que possamos executar e ver o problema. De onde vem `$arrayDados2`? Pelo que vi parece um problema de com `utf8`, mas não nos headers e sim como o arquivo foi salvo, pode ser outro arquivo no servidor que esta sendo usado com `include`.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: A questão de aparecer o Ênio Lima, funcionou, eu pego os dados de uma página ASP que escreve apenas os nomes dos usuários separados por ";", essa página ASP não estava com codificação utf-8, nem possuía cabeçalhos. Depois, populo o `$arrayDados2`, o problema agora é que o "Ênio Lima" fica no topo, ou seja não ordena.

Answer (score 0):

Você está rodando este código no contexto de uma página Web? Pode ser que a página não esteja em UTF-8, então as strings podem estar sendo recebidas no formato ISO-8859-1, o que explica inclusive por que o "Ê" foi corrompido.

Se for Apache, tente usar

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

na configuração, e verifique se a página PHP tenha a declaração

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: Sim, estou utilizando no contexto que você mencionou `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` ... Você sabe me dizer se o Bootstrap altera alguma configuração de codificação de página? Pois estou utilizando ele e aparentemente isso que tá mexendo com a questão do "Ê" corrompido. Mas fiz o teste, removi o **Bootstrap** da página mesmo assim não ordenou corretamente o "Ênio Lima" ficou no topo.